# Adding timestamp to video export in Google Earth Engine

Tags: modis, google-earth-engine

I am exporting an image collection to video using:

```js
Export.video.toDrive({
  collection: mov_EVI,
  description: 'Modis EVI-Classified Water',
  dimensions: 720,
  framesPerSecond: 10,
  region:ROI
});
```

How can I add a timestamp to the export frames of the video using `system:time_start` of each image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a code that I found from an answer from google-earth-engine developers group by Gennadii Donchyts:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/6270df443326ec0d90a18838bd91c5a5

Essentially, a package has been written in GEE to annotate on ee.Image object, which then can be exported as the video.

Comment: If this answered your initial question please mark it as the correct answer using the grey/green arrow on the left side.

Comment: Tried to adjust this using a different dataset and a fixed label text, but get the error message `text.annnotateImage is not a function`.

Comment: See here - you need to import the package at the beginning
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/366055/how-to-add-a-timeline-tool-to-time-lapse-in-gee?noredirect=1&lq=1