# How to annotate features in google earth engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have a CSV file with ID, X, Y, NAME and ZoomLabel. I have been successful with putting the Point Feature on the map.

Now I am trying to annotate the locations with the NAME field.

I used the following code and uploaded the CSV file, yet the annotation does not appear, what feature/command should I use. This is the code which I'm trying to run for getting the text on the map?

```
// Load the CSV file as a table
var table = ee.FeatureCollection('users/yourUsername/path/to/test.csv');

// Define a visualization style for the points (red color)
var pointStyle = {
  color: 'FF0000', // Red color
  pointSize: 5,
  width: 1,
};

// Add the points to the map with the specified style
Map.addLayer(table, pointStyle, 'Points');

// Define a function to create text annotations from the NAME column
function addTextAnnotations(feature) {
  // Extract the NAME property
  var name = ee.String(feature.get('NAME'));
 
  // Create a text annotation
  var annotation = ee.Feature(feature.geometry()).set('text', name);
 
  return annotation;
}

// Map the text annotations over the feature collection
var textAnnotations = table.map(addTextAnnotations);

// Create a text visualization style
var textStyle = {
  fontSize: 12,
  color: '000000', // Black color
};

// Add the text annotations to the map with the specified style
Map.addLayer(textAnnotations.style(textStyle), {}, 'Annotations');

// Center the map on the points
Map.centerObject(table, 10); // You can adjust the zoom level (10 in this case) to your preference
```

Answer (score 0):

`style()` doesn't do text.  Your only option is the text module from gena.  See this previous question:

[Google Earth Engine - Add text label at lat/lon location?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/326899/google-earth-engine-add-text-label-at-lat-lon-location)