# How to add a Timeline tool to Time Lapse in GEE?

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, time, video

I have been struggling to add a timeline tool to a time-lapse video I put together on GEE... The last part of my code is:

```
var polygon = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-XX,-XX,-XX,-XX]); //xMin, yMin, xMax, yMax.

var videoArgs = {
  collection: collection,
  description: 'VideoExample',
  dimensions: 600,
  framesPerSecond: 10,
  region: polygon
};

print(collection.getVideoThumbURL(videoArgs));
```

How would it be possible to add a timeline tool to the video representing the changes over time for my collection? How can I pass the date of each image to the timeline tool and then to the video?

Comment: What part of your question was not already answered here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/272548/adding-timestamp-to-video-export-in-google-earth-engine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To add timestamps to timelapse, you need to add text overlays to each frame using the example from [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/326899/google-earth-engine-add-text-label-at-lat-lon-location). It is based on [gena's](https://github.com/gena) textoverlay package.

To import that package use :`var text = require('users/gena/packages:text')`.

Then create a function that adds a property called `label` to each image in your stack with the timestamp of your choice. Finally, print/export your videoThumbURL as usual.

**Link to complete working example is [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/de742ed3d29179ea591712428c55a3a7).** The base visualization was obtained from the [Image Visualization documentation](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/ic_visualization). The result of the working example is provided below.

[image]

The text is pixelated since Earth Engine doesn't inherently support text elements in its `Map` environment. So the package is a workaround to create image elements that look like text.

Comment: Awesome... thanks for your help kkrao ! ... I made it work ... now I am wondering  how could I do the same strategy to include the legend in the video as well... I understand that you pass the time as a dynamic string, but how can I do the same for a Legend?. I have been able to include a Legend on the console...

  var legend          = ui.Panel({style:{position: 'bottom-left',padding:'8px 15px'}});
  var legendTitle     = ui.Label({value:'Temperature-2m (Celsius).......etc...

I was able to add the panels to the console but how do I visualize it in the video as an annotation?