# Timestamp video/time-series in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I successfully managed to output a video time-series of processed Sentinel 1 SAR images in GEE for my areas and dates of interest by adapting an existing script. However, I've not been able to timestamp it.
I have tried working off some help provided to the following two discussions and scripts within, but with no success.
[Adding timestamp to video export in Google Earth Engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/272548/adding-timestamp-to-video-export-in-google-earth-engine)
[How to add a Timeline tool to Time Lapse in GEE?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/366055/how-to-add-a-timeline-tool-to-time-lapse-in-gee?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I have tried many things with many errors, but my error with the script at its current state is:

```
Collection.iterate: Error in map(ID=1):
Date: Parameter 'value' is required.
    in <global>, line 165
    in <global>, line 175
```

This is my full code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/b1f180b3f823680d8d138dee1d0536bc and the portion that I use to try to timestamp is below:

```
var text = require('users/gena/packages:text');
var S1_comp =  S1_comp.map(function(image){
  var start = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start'));
  var end = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_end'));
  var label = start.format('YYYY-MM-dd').cat(' - ').cat(end.format('YYYY-MM-dd'));
  
  return image.visualize({
    forceRgbOutput: true,
    //palette: palettes.BrBG[9], //original palette was "000000", "fdbb84"
    //min: 0,
    //max: 1
  }).clip(roi).set({label: label}); 
});

// annotate
var annotations = [
  {
    position: 'left', offset: '1%', margin: '1%', property: 'label', scale: Map.getScale() * 2
  }
]

S1_comp = S1_comp.map(function(image) {
  return text.annotateImage(image, {}, roi, annotations)  
});
```

Comment: For the record, I didn't find an answer to this - I timestamped the video in python after creating it in GEE.

Comment: How did you timestamped it in Python?